# Laravel Eloquent multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a complex setup which includes the following tables.

```
Customers
Transactions
Jobs
Rounds
Job_Rounds
```

I want to output all the customers which are overdue. I've done that by using the following query:

```
$data = Auth::user()->clients()->leftjoin('transactions','clients.id','=','transactions.client_id')
                ->select(DB::raw('sum(gross) as value, email, first_name, last_name, mobile, clients.id, addressline1'))
                ->groupBy('id','first_name','last_name','email','mobile','addressline1', 'clients.id')
                ->havingRaw('SUM(gross) < 0')
                ->get();
```

That returns all the customers which are overdue which is great, however I now want to be able to filter the overdue customers by round.

My relationships are as follows:

```
Customers > Jobs.client_id
Customers > Transactions.client_id
Jobs > Rounds via Jobs_Rounds
```

I would pass to my controller the round_id of a given round and then try to filter the results based on the round_id. the only place I'm storing the round ID is in the jobs_rounds table and that table only contains job_id & round_id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about using the HasManyThrough relationship to link a `Customer` and a `Round`.

Something like this :

```
// Customer.php
public function rounds()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Round::class, Job::class, 'client_id', 'job_id', 'id');
}
```

Then in your controller you could try this :

```
$data = Auth::user()->clients()
            ->whereHas('rounds', function ($query) {
                $query->where('id', request()->input('round_id'))
            })
            //... the rest of your filters
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I've tried this but I seem to be having an issue.. When I return Client::First()->rounds I expected to see the clients rounds but I get the error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rounds.job_id' - the link between the round and the client would be through.. Job which is linked to the client, the job is linked to a round via job_rounds

Comment: Seems like you don't have a `job_id` in your `rounds` table